# Pointer to functions

Tags: php

I made a class that uses the SoapClient object and receives, in the constructor, the webservice url and the association between the methods and the responses.

With it I have a call function that only receives the method and its parameters!

But I want to do a little more generalization!

I want to pass to the constructor the methods in a way that permit me to register them as functions and call them directly!

I've seen this done in C, and I believe it can be made in PHP!

Can anyone give me a hint?

With the help of Waleed Khan and with some more research I've figured out how to do it!

on the file that uses my class I use this

```
$webs=new WebserviceCLS('webserviceIP',array("GetData"=>"GetDataResult"),array("GetData"));

$webs->metodo['GetData']($webs,array ("idData" => "98745684"));
```

and in the constructor of the class I use

```
foreach($met as $v)
{
    $eu = $this;
    $this->metodo[$v]= function($param) use($v,$eu)
    {
        $eu->call($v,$param);
    };
}
```

This way the constructor gets the method list for the webservice and makes an anonymous function that calls a generic handler for the webservice. To make that call I use the variable $eu wich points to the class and is used in the anonymous function

Comment: PHP since 5.3 lets you make and pass [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), and all recent versions of PHP let you pass a string name which you can then call as if it were the name of a function.

Comment: In PHP 5.4 you can also [bind closures to objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php).

Comment: My current problem is calling a function in the parent of my anonymous funtions! any hint?

Comment: I didn't understand why it is off topic! I showed effort to resolve my question! I even responded myself to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment the repetition of the caller in the invokation and add a stupid line in the class!

Caller:

```
$webs->metodo['GetCliente'](array ("idCliente" => "98745684"));
```

Class:

```
foreach($met as $v)
{
    $eu = $this;
    $this->metodo[$v]= function($param) use($v,$eu)
    {
        $eu->call($v,$param);
    };
}
```

And now I can invoke webservices as if it is just another PHP class!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint from Waleed Khan I was able to continue the pursue of the answer to my question which is almost completely solved!

I've haded an extra parameter to the anonymous function and with it I solved my problem!

my code is now this:

```
$webs=new WebserviceCLS('http://94.46.227.3/alidata/service.asmx?    WSDL',array("GetCliente"=>"GetClienteResult"),array("GetCliente"));

$webs->metodo['GetCliente']($webs,array ("idCliente" => "98745684"));
```

On the consumer side!

and this:

```
foreach($met as $v)
{
    $this->metodo[$v]= function($obj,$param) use($v);
    {
        $obj->call($v,$param);
    };
}
```

on the webservice class!

My next step is to make this a singleton, and hopefully be able to quit the extra $obj parameter

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Correction! I cannot make a singleton out of this because I may need to use several webservices from several urls! But I still need to get rid of that extra parameter!

Comment: Is there a way to invoke the caller object through the called anonymous function?